# PHP: combining same-length arrays into a multidimensional array where both end up as values (not keys)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two same-length arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

And I want to end up with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```

`array_combine` would make one set of the above values into array *keys*, which I don't want -- I want both to end up as array values, combining each item of the two arrays into a new array.

Is there a built in function to do this or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a built in function to do this

**Yes**

> or do I have to roll my own?

**No**

By calling `array_map()` and feeding it `null` as the callback parameter, then feeding it 2 or more arrays, it will restructure your data as desired.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f8C7g))

```
$array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array2 = [1, 2, 3];

var_export(array_map(null, $array1, $array2));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'b',
    1 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'c',
    1 => 3,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $val) {
    $result[] = array($val, $array2[$i]);
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Jx5H1Q

Comment: what if there are three arrays?

Comment: @AlphaMale `$result[] = array($val, $array2[$i], $array3[$i]);`

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you had string keys, you could use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/array-merge-recursive) to merge them. As it is, though, you'll need to do something else. For instance:

```
$result = Array();
$arrays = Array($array1,$array2...);
foreach($arrays as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v) $result[$k][] = $v;
}
```

Comment: While the solution is simple, please explain what your snippet does for the benefit of researchers that are new to php / programming.